# the button is missing after set its parameter in Tablelayout

Tags: android, button

I want to set the size of button programmatically in the Tablelayout which is in ScrollView.

here is my XML file

```
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbarFadeDuration="1000"
    android:scrollbarSize="12dip" >
<TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tablay"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/open" />
    <TableRow>
          <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="16sp"
            android:layout_height="16sp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Delete"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout> 
</ScrollView>
```

here is my java file

```
private void setList(){ 
/* Create a new row to be added. */
     TableRow tr;
     ImageButton delbtn;
     int btnsize;
    tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    delbtn = new ImageButton(this);
    //delbtn.setText("Delete");
    //delbtn.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,sys_def_char_font);
    btnsize = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, sys_def_char_font, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    delbtn.setId(i);
    delbtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_delete);
    delbtn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(btnsize,btnsize));
    tr.addView(delbtn);
    tablay.addView(tr);
}
```

If I add button mutually in xml file, then everything is alright.

But I try to add it programmatically. And since I want to make the button which I added programmatically
smaller, I use setLayoutParams to set parameters.

However, the button which I added programmatically is missing after setLayoutParams().

Please, can anybody tell me where the wrong is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code by changing `sys_def_char_font` to `5` and it worked fine. I can see the `TableRow` added with the `button`.

I reckon the problem is in the following line...

```
btnsize = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, sys_def_char_font, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

What is `sys_def_char_font`? Where have you declared it?

I suggest you check what `sys_def_char_font` is. The [**DOCS**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html) says it has to be a `float`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I declared sys_def_char_font at the very beginning. It's an integer value "20".  After I tried your suggestion, I found out that the size of screen led to this problem.
Anyway, thanks for answering my question.